# Tiktok algorithm UI

Tags: python

Essentially, I created the ui and everthing seems to be working fine until i press the button to geet my ranking.

```
from email.mime import image
import random
import os
from struct import pack
import webbrowser 
import tkinter





# share_count = int(input("How many shares did you get on your last tiktok "))
# like_count = int(input("How many likes did you get on your last tiktok "))
# comment_count = int(input("How many comments did you get on your last tiktok "))
# posts = int(input("How many posts do you have on your tiktok page "))
def magic_algorithm(share_count, like_count, comment_count, posts):
    if share_count >= 10000 and like_count >= 5000 and comment_count > 200 and posts >20:
        rank = 1 
    elif share_count >= 7000 and like_count >= 2000 and comment_count > 60 and posts >25:
        rank = random.randint(2,10)
    elif share_count >= 6000 and like_count >= 1500 and comment_count > 50 and posts >25:
        rank = random.randint(11,20)
    elif share_count >= 5000 and like_count >= 1300 and comment_count > 33 and posts >20:
        rank = random.randint(21,40)
    elif share_count >= 4000 and like_count >= 1000 and comment_count > 25 and posts >15:
        rank = random.randint(41,55)
    elif share_count >= 3000 and like_count >= 500 and comment_count > 15 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(56,70)
    elif share_count >= 2000 and like_count >= 300 and comment_count > 10 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(71,80)
    elif share_count >= 1000 and like_count >= 150 and comment_count > 10 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(81,90)
    elif share_count >= 400 and like_count >= 100 and comment_count > 5 and posts >11:
        rank = random.randint(91,97)
    else:
        rank = random.randint(98,100)
    return(rank)

def calculate_ranking():
    #read in entry values 
    like_count = int(like_entry.get())
    comment_count = comments_entry.get()
    share_count = share_entry.get()
    posts = posts_entry.get()
    #pass values into magic algorithm 
    #print result to result label 
    rank = str(magic_algorithm(like_count, share_count, posts,comment_count))

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Main Tiktok Page")
root.geometry ("400x600")

likes_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="number of likes:")
likes_label.pack()
like_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
like_entry.pack()

#shares
share_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="number of shares:")
share_label.pack()
share_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
share_entry.pack()
#comments
comments_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Comment:")
comments_label.pack()
comments_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
comments_entry.pack()
#posts
posts_label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Posts")
posts_label.pack()
posts_entry = tkinter.Entry(root)
posts_entry.pack()

image
img_path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "\\tiktok-tricks-09.PNG"
tiktok_image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=img_path)
resized_tiktok_img = tiktok_image.subsample(4,4) 
image_label = tkinter.Label(root, image=resized_tiktok_img)
image_label.pack()



#rank button
rank_button = tkinter.Button(root, text = "get ranking", command=calculate_ranking)
rank_button.pack()

#result
result_label = tkinter.Label(root, text ="Your tiktok ranking is ")
result_label.pack
root.mainloop()
```

But then when I enter all my parameters it gives me an error saying:

```
 line 48, in calculate_ranking
    rank = str(magic_algorithm(like_count, share_count, posts,comment_count))

  , line 18, in magic_algorithm
    **if share_count >= 10000 and like_count >= 5000 and comment_count > 200 and posts >20:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'**
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message should give you a clue. It means that you are comparing a string with an integer with `>=`. So that means one of those variables, like `comment_count` is a string. But it should be an integer.

So change this:

```
    like_count = int(like_entry.get())
    comment_count = comments_entry.get()
    share_count = share_entry.get()
    posts = posts_entry.get()
```

To this:

```
    like_count = int(like_entry.get())
    comment_count = int(comments_entry.get())
    share_count = int(share_entry.get())
    posts = int(posts_entry.get())
```

Comment: thanks it worked also for some reason my getting another error on line 89 saying AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'? is there a solution

Comment: That's a different question. Please ask a new question -- after you have debugged your code and tried to find a solution yourself.